# All prime ideals are invertible $\Rightarrow$ Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

$\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}$ $\newcommand{\a}{\mathfrak{a}}$
Let $A$ be a one-dimensional Noetherian domain.
I am thinking about this claim:

> If all prime ideals of $A$ are invertible, then $A$ is a Dedekind domain.

Is that true?

I tried to show a unique factorization into prime ideals.
Indeed, an integral domain is a Dedekind domain,
iff all nonzero ideals admit a unique prime factorization.

To show this, I'm going to show following two lemmas.
If it is proved, we can prove a unique factorization
by the same way as a Dedekind domain (cf. Neukirch, *Algebraic Number Theory*).

Let $\a \neq 0$ be an ideal of $A$.
I proved the first lemma:

> There exists prime ideals $\p_1, \dots, \p_r$ such that
>   $$
> \a \supseteq \p_1\dots \p_r
> $$

by the same way as a Dedekind domain,
because it is not used that $A$ is integrally closed.

But I can't show the second lemma:

> $$\a\p^{-1} \supsetneq \a.$$

I found that to show the second lemma, it is sufficient to show that
$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \p^n = 0. \label{a}\tag{1}$$
We assume that it is proved.
If $\a\p^{-1} = \a$, $\a = \a\p$.
By induction, we get $\a = \a\p^n$ for $\forall n > 0$.
We use $\eqref{a}$, then we get $\a = 0$.
It is a contradiction.

However, I can't prove $\eqref{a}$.

Comment: How do you define invertible ideal?

Comment: @oxeimon $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = 1$ for
$\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = \{x \in \mathrm{Frac}(A) \mid x\mathfrak{a} \subset A \}$.

Comment: Though it is a different way from my thought, what I want to show is proved in linked question.

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607305/in-a-noetherian-ring-every-non-zero-prime-ideal-is-invertible-implies-every-non

Comment: @nohm Ask proving (1) as a different question. The present question is more or less settled by my answer.

Comment: @user26857 I see. By your answer, $A$ is a Dedekind domain now. If $a \in \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \mathfrak{p}^n$, then $\mathfrak{p}^n \mid (a)$ for $\forall n$. By a unique factorization, $(a)=0$, so $a=0$.

Comment: @nohm Sure, but the property holds for noetherian domains, in general. See http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Krull_intersection_theorem_for_Noetherian_domains

Comment: @user26857 I understand. Then, I succeeded in my first attempt, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathfrak a\mathfrak p^{-1}=\mathfrak a$, then $\mathfrak a\mathfrak p=\mathfrak a$. Moreover $(\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p})(\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p})=\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}$. By Nakayama lemma we get $\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}=0$, so $\mathfrak a=0$ which I suppose you don't want.

Comment: Why Nakayama's lemma can be applied? As $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: @nohm Can you see a maximal ideal in my answer? And what about a finitely generated module?

Comment: I see that $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal of $A_\mathfrak{p}$. I can't see a finitely generated module.

Comment: @nohm What about $\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}$ (as an $A_{\mathfrak p}$-module)? (Since $\mathfrak a$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, then...)

Comment: I see $\mathfrak{a}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a finitely generated module, but I think Statement 3 of this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma) can't be applied.

Comment: @nohm Why do you think so? (Have you tried $N=0$?)

Comment: If it was $(\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}) + (\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p})=\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}$, it could be OK, but it is multiplicative form now.

Comment: $\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}$ and $(\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$ are modules with addition, so I thought it must be an additive form... I'll think, thanks.

Comment: @nohm The most common form of Nakayama's lemma says: let $R$ be a local ring, $\mathfrak m$ its maximal ideal, and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. If $\mathfrak mM=M$ then $M=0$. (Now guess which objects are these in my answer.)

Comment: At last, I noticed my mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The proof I know for the second lemma also assumes that $A$ is integrally closed: since $1\in \mathfrak{p}^{-1}$ we have $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \mathfrak{ap}^{-1}$. So we have to show that the inclusion is strict. Assume that $\mathfrak{a}= \mathfrak{ap}^{-1}$. Let $a\in \mathfrak{p}^{-1}$. Then $a$ is integral over $A$ iff there is a finitely-generated $A$-module $N$ with $Na\subseteq N$. But $\mathfrak{a}$ is such an $A$-module, so that $a$ is indeed integral. Since $A$ is integrally closed, we must have $a\in A$, i.e., $\mathfrak{p}^{-1}\subseteq \mathfrak{a}$. Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal, and $A$ is a Noetherian domain of dimension $1$, we obtain $A\subsetneq \mathfrak{p}^{-1}\subseteq \mathfrak{a}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Should the last containment say $A \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ instead?

Comment: No, the results is that a maximal Ideal $M$ in a Dedekind ring $A$ satisfies $A\subsetneq M^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, your additional edit clarifies.  With your original wording, I thought that was supposed to be the contradiction.  It makes sense now.  Thanks.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This proof seems to be using that A is a Dedekind domain, but we only assume that A is a one-dimensional Noetherian domain and all prime ideals are invertible.